# Are Meta Keywords Case Sensitive?

Tags: html, seo, web-crawler, meta-tags

Is

```
<meta name="keywords" content="mykeyword, Mykeyword">
```

the same thing as

```
<meta name="keywords" content="mykeyword">
```

Are both keywords considered the same by a web crawler?

Comment: This is off topic, and should be migrated to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Negative, I think this is as a good a place as any for this question

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They're not case sensitive, but they are useless from an SEO point http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/keywords-meta-tag-in-web-search/

If you search for "People" and "people", you'd get the same results. Word case isn't important in title tags, header tags, or any other tags, so they shouldn't matter in meta tag, either. So for all practical purposes, "people" and "People" is the same word for the crawler.

Comment: anyways, it would've been hilarious if you'd get totally different results due to case mismatches :)) . good explanation +1

Comment: What's the point in this meta tag then? What other purpose might it have?

Comment: The original purpose was probably just for that - to describe the page to search engines. Once search engine makers realized how the tag can be exploited for spamming reasons, they chose to ignore the tag.